# Lua Breakout Game Tutorial : Weird behavior of ball

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/06/07/tutorial-create-a-breakout-game-in-corona-sdk/) to make a breakout game, but at some point, the ball keeps leaning on the top wall when the ball angle is too large ( too horizontal ). Is there any logic I can tune so that the ball can avoid this behavior?

Here is the screenshot :

[image: screenshot]

The ball's related source code is:

```
local ballRadius = 10
ball = display.newCircle( display.contentWidth / 2, display.contentHeight / 2, ballRadius )
physics.addBody(ball, "dynamic", {friction=0, bounce = 1, radius=ballRadius})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is some kind of weird. But I've done once like this...

Create 3 variables/flags:

```
local horizontalMotionFlag,yPos_1,yPos_2 = 0,0,0
```

Then:

```
wall.type = "LeftWall"  -- to the LeftWall
            -- and --
wall.type = "RightWall"  -- to the RightWall
```

Add the following lines inside `event.phase == "ended"`

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if(event.other.type == "LeftWall") then
    yPos_1 = ball.y
    if(horizontalMotionFlag==0)then
        horizontalMotionFlag = 1
    else
        if(math.abs(yPos_1-yPos_2) < 50)then
            print("CoHorizontal motion detected. Change angle...1")
            horizontalMotionFlag = 0
            ball:applyForce( 0, 1, ball.x, ball.y )  -- apply a small downward force
            ball:applyForce( 0, 0, ball.x, ball.y )  -- resetting the force
            -- You can also check the direction of ball and apply force to -1(upwards) also --
        end
    end
end

if(event.other.type == "RightWall") then
    yPos_2 = ball.y
    if(horizontalMotionFlag==0)then
        horizontalMotionFlag = 1
    else
        if(math.abs(yPos_1-yPos_2) < 50)then
            print("CoHorizontal motion detected. Change angle...")
            horizontalMotionFlag = 0
            ball:applyForce( 0, 1, ball.x, ball.y )  -- apply a small downward force
            ball:applyForce( 0, 0, ball.x, ball.y )  -- resetting the force
            -- You can also check the direction of ball and apply force to -1(upwards) also --
        end
    end
end
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then add the following line inside `event.other.type == "destructible"` and `event.other.type == "bottomWall"` :

```
horizontalMotionFlag = 0;
```

Keep Coding............. :)